# Increment not working on For looping vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i just made a model to put checkbox value inside an array. But, i had a problem when i'm trying to map the index. The problem is, the increment is just doing nothing. I try to console.log it but the value keep showing 0.

Here's my model:

```
data: function () {
  return {
    id: null,
    editor: false,
    loading: false,
    valid: false,
    checks: [],
    field: [],
    form: {
      name: 'asd',
      description: 'asd',
      data: [
        {
          menu_id: '',
          user_type_id: '1',
        },
      ],
    },
    file: null,
    url: null,
  }
},
```

And here's my function to set the data:

```
async setDetail () {
    this.form.name = this.form.name
    this.form.description = this.form.description
    for (var i = 0; i < this.form.data.length; i++) {
      this.form.data[i].menu_id = this.field[i].menu_id
      this.form.data[i].user_type_id = this.form.data[i].user_type_id
      console.log(this.form.data[i])
      console.log(this.field)
      console.log(i)
    }
  },
```

Every time i check more than one checkbox, it always show output like this:
[image]

Hopefully you guys could help telling me what's wrong with it.
Thank you

Comment: How are you calling `setDetail`?

Comment: Are you adding anything to the array? From your code, you're just reassigning what's already there

Comment: the setDetail @change property which I set in checkbox, just to make sure the value what i choose is added to form.data.menu_id. The objective is i want to assign every value based on checked checkbox and put it in form.data.menu_id

Comment: You should create an object and then push that object to the array instead